# Travis CI does not hold on PHP's exit()

Tags: php, continuous-integration, cgi, travis-ci

in opposite to most questions: I cannot make Travis CI to fail when my PHP cgi script returns an `exit()`, `exit(0)`, `exit(1)`, `die()` or `return false`.

It performs the exit() but happily continues without hold on a failure.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was my fault or just a stupid default setup.

I'm using [Grunt Shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) and just missed to set an option called "failOnError" to true.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot it... Done